# Reputation tab displaying weird/wrong dates?

Tags: bug

So, last night I saw a chat message from someone stating their reputation tab looked weird, and today I experienced the same thing myself, on Interpersonal Skills:

- The graph displays a rep gain from 2015 onwards (note that this is on a beta site, so it should really have started nowhere before 2017).
- The post tab didn't show reputation today, instead, supposedly my last rep gain was from late January (on the first page)
- Going back to page 18 (there's only supposed to be 7), apparently, I started gaining reputation in 2008.

Refreshing the page didn't solve the issue immediately, but after visiting the time and graph tabs (and seeing they were okay), when returning to the post tab everything was fine again...

Proof:

[image: for point 1/2]

[image: for point 3]

#### Update:

- It happened again this morning, but now the time and graph tabs were wrong as well
- The 11 posts edited is wrong as well, this should be over a 100.
- Tried clearing my cache and reloading the page, the reputation tab looks normal again but the 'posts edited' count is still wrong.

[image: time tab]

[image: graph tab.]

Comment: Which site is this on?

Comment: Oh.... Interpersonal Skills :) Trust me to forget the obvious stuff :/

Comment: I see y'all are having lots of fun serving SO data to no-SO sites. :P https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599/mrvaldez?tab=topactivity

Comment: @Catija Yeah, I was wondering if this was that same thing.

Comment: Oh cool, I have SO rep now? :D it does match, so that's what happened...

Comment: @AdamLear Why was this marked a dupe of an (unanswered) question posted 2 days *after* this one?

Comment: @WELZ Because the other one had a dev response and the age of question is not and has never been the primary criterion for dupe targets.