# Phantom rep, plus privileges? Audit says I should have 1374, but the site is showing 5922

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation

At some point in the past day I seem to have gained roughly 4547 reputation. There's no entry on my reputation page that would explain it, and my reputation audit shows an end result of 1374. I've also gained all relevant privileges, such as voting to close.

[image]

Reputation leagues show a more realistic number:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta/2021-01-01/200898#200898

[image]

Comment: Guess: They're serving SO rep again, just like when I asked [my first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307173/369802) here. [User number 200898](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200898/moss) on SO has 5922 rep...

Comment: Interesting how upvotes on this question are incrementing it, assuming that's the case

Comment: There's https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation that might help.

Comment: And a _lot_ of new Yearling badges followed.

Comment: seems it isn't just affecting me

Comment: Similar things happen for me too, on Meta I should have 131 rep, but I get shown 9.342, which is also in no clear relation to my SO rep (1.052) or my total summed up rep (3.096).

Comment: @KevinB no, it's not just you. And it's not just people getting reputation either, [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/231933/alexander-gruber?tab=profile) seems to have lost all of theirs for a while. I'm curious if that has an effect on their privileges here.

Comment: If my case is anything to go by, I'd assume they lost their privileges just like I gained some. (I have confirmed the privileges actually work)

Comment: @TobiasF. the way this works is that it isn't showing you *your* SO rep, but that of a total stranger that has the same user id on SO as you have on MSE (in this case, 402870). So you're seeing the reputation of https://stackoverflow.com/users/402870/iamnan

Comment: I just noticed this about my own rep due to yearling badges. I searched but found nothing until I went to the main M.SE feed. The way you have phrased the issues in this post make it very unlikely anyone else could find it searching.

Comment: We're investigating

Comment: And we're working on a fix.

Comment: On your [MSE profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/200898/kevin-b?tab=profile), I presume. What is it *now*?

Comment: It is now 1424, aka correct

Comment: @Taryn also see the case of [this user](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8950641#8950641).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This has not been a good week! A global re-sync route that synced main users to their meta equivalents (which itself needed to happen because the profile image code is icky) had a code path that persisted rep to the database of wherever the route was executed rather than the one we were supposed to be operating on.

In this case I was syncing Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow but executing the route via Meta Stack Exchange - that meant that *user ids* from Stack Overflow ended up trampling rep on their Meta Stack Exchange equivalents. Fortunately we have ample history to restore rep to its correct value - that process is wrapping up now and we'll remove inadvertently granted "Yearling" badges when it's done.

---

**UPDATE**

Inadvertently granted yearling badges have been revoked, things are back as they should be.

Apologies for the surprise!