# Why/how did this user have a 'Yearling' badge shown on the network profile on July 22, 2021 but not on the site?

Tags: support, bug, yearling-badge

[The network profile of this user](https://stackexchange.com/users/16422183/mba?tab=activity) shows that they got a Yearling badge on Meta Stack Exchange on July 22, 2021.

> [image]

However, clicking the badge redirects to [the badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=582294) showing that this user "did not earn this badge".

> [image]

Why/how did this user have a 'Yearling' badge shown on the network profile?

Comment: For the Yearling badge you need to have earned at least 200 rep, so it seems they shouldn't have received one in the first place.

Comment: @Joachim more likely there was a badge, the  user lost reputation, created new account, the new account was merged into the old account and the badge was gone. When accounts merge, badges are re-calculated. And network profile data sit in different place, that isn't always synchronized with the "live" data. Still, just my own observation, better have it confirmed officially. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron That indeed sounds like a logical conclusion. I can imagine 'badge activity' is not 'recalculated' or retroactively adjusted.

Comment: For reference: footnote 2 of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/377214) explains how badge rewards work for merged accounts.

Comment: It is related to [this past bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367704/phantom-rep-plus-privileges-audit-says-i-should-have-1374-but-the-site-is-sho) which incorrectly calculated a bunch of reputation for users. They were awarded the badge and it was revoked, but the revocation never propagated to the network profile (I'm not sure if they are even designed to given we almost never revoke these badges).